# Having trouble running android sdk tool on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: java, android, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

When I try to run the Android SDK Manager from the command line it doesn't open.
Keeps giving me command not found or permission denied message like so.

```
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$ pwd
/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$ /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
bash: /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: Permission denied
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$ sudo /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
sudo: /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: command not found
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$
```

Am I missing something? Am i doing something wrong? Please help.

Comment: Does it have execution permissions? Try doing `chmod +x executable` and then execute again.

Comment: @AdriánLópez I did `chmod -R +x <path to executable>`. but I still got `command not found`

Comment: `android` is just a shell script, run it with `bash -x android` and see what it prints out.

Comment: @DanielFekete that did the job. but i still think i will encounter this again when i will try to run the adb. Also eclipse did run this but could not initiate the adb and said `permission denied`. I'll see what that is later but can you tell me what did the `bash` command do?

Comment: `android` is just a shell script (text file), you can open in editor, the first line tells which program can run it. First line it is `#!/bin/sh`, and I assumed it is `bash` on your system. Anyway you can further debug this problem with running this: `/bin/sh -x android`, and get more information on what is `/bin/sh` on your system by running `ls -l /bin/sh`

Comment: /media is an unusual path for a tools installation, what kind of file system is it?  If its some variant of FAT on a usb drive you will have no end of trouble running unix style programs from there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

cd your way to android-sdks/tools, then try:

```
sudo ./android
```

Comment: Please don't, this should not be necessary and the code is not written with being run as root in mind.

Comment: Well yes, obviously, but because his android-sdks folder is not in /home, what do you expect ?

Comment: Running it as root is the wrong thing to do, and likely has nothing significant to do with the problem anyway.

Comment: I know it is wrong, the correct solution was to move it to /home, as he did. Case closed perfectly. Happy ?